# Bind click event to jquery.appear

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the plugin Jquery.appear for a project I'm working with. It works great and it's issue free, but I'm curious to know if I can bind a click event to it. Basically what I'm after is when I scroll to a certain div down the page, an event fires, easy. However, I also would like to make it so I can have a 'click' event fire off as well but without the user actually clicking. So I was thinking using bind would make this possible. I'll include what I have below.

```
$(function() {
  var $appeared = $('#boost-que');
  $('#boost-que').appear();
  $(document.body).one('appear', '#boost-que', function(e, $affected) {
    function testScroll() {
      alert('works');
    }
    $(document.body).bind('click', testScroll);
    $appeared.empty();
  });
});
```

This works, but I have to physically click to make the click event fire. Is there a way to bind the click event so it will fire by itself? Any input is always appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you call function?

Comment: @A.Wolff That what I was trying to do with the testScroll() function to test out. Using the suggestion below I think I can hack out the rest of what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically click it by calling `click()` after binding:

```
$(document.body).bind('click', testScroll).click();
```

or:

```
$(document.body).bind('click', testScroll).trigger("click");
```